# Couchbase: Sync data with conditions

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am building chat application where mobile app user keeps data on his device. We try to sync only user-related data from the server to client( couchbase server to couchbase mobile ). But from mobile using swift all Bucket is stored from server to mobile internal db. My sync json is

```
{
  "interface": "192.168.0.68:4984",
  "adminInterface": "192.168.0.68:4985",
  "pretty": true,
  "log": ["*"],
  "databases": {
    "db": {
        "server": "http://192.168.0.68:8091",
        "bucket": "travel-sample",

        "username":"himanshu",
        "password":"123456",
        "users": {
            "himanshu": {
              "password": "123456",
              "admin_channels": [
                "*"
              ]
            }
          },
        "sync":`
            function (doc) {
                console.log("doc=================================================================>")
                channel (doc.channels);
            }
        `   
    }
}}
```

It is possible that server send only related data to mobile for sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieve using proper configuration of Channels for each user to define access and can restrict users.

The sync function is allowed to grant users access to channels based on the contents of documents

In this case when you create a document it's properties should indicate that a particular user has created/edited and based on that the sync function kicks in to get the replication going on.

Create an array of tags based on document type a given user interested in to replicate on mobile and pass this in your sync function

```
{ 
  "tags" : [
    "fashion",
    "outing",
    "shopping"
   ]
}
```

and Sync function would be similar as

```
function(doc) {
  channel(doc.tags);
}
```

ON a client end synchronize the relevant user content by using built in replication API  , which set up the user's topic interest to pull relevant data. The replicator will then interact with the data from channels. Create a pull replication as in Objective-C code

```
CBLReplication *pull = [database createPullReplication: url];
pull.channels = @[@"outing",@"shopping"];
[pull start];
```

If we have not set the specific channel then probably all the data that exists will be pull down from Sync Gateway.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should make use of [Sync Gateway channels](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/channels/index.html) to route the proper data so the device.  As part of your Sync function, if you route the data to a "mobile channel" for example and either set this channel on your replicator, or set up authentication for a mobile user who only has access to this channel then you will only get that specific data.